# Crystal 2008 Chart legend Font Issue - exported pdf file

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have an rpt file designed using crystal 8.5. I opened this file in crystal 2008 and saved it. after exporting the report to pdf, the letters in the chart legend appear too close to each other. I tried different font sizes no luck.

How to increase the letter spacing in chart legend in crystal 2008 or how to make the text appear good in the chart legend

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the ability to change letter spacing. The only luck I've really had with it is modifying the location/size of the legend. I usually find that placing it on the bottom of the chart, increasing the font size, and adding a space preceding the legend text is the best setup for readability in a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Chords. I tried the options you gave. still no luck.